# Maps voice directions revert to a different language

Tags: google-maps-navigation, lg-g2

Often when I use Google maps voice navigation from from LG G2 phone, the voice will change to a different language (should be English but seems to be French).

I can't find a setting or cause for this?

Comment: Did you check the installed voice languages on your device?

Comment: I just checked it and strangely to Google text to speech component was set to Brazilian.  I thought I had checked all these previously when the problems arose????  hopefully that has fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Should I write it as an answer instead of a comment?